# SSMS Color tab based on connection string / Environment

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-2014, ssms-2016, ssms-2017

SQL Server - SSMS

Can we change the SSMS query tab color based on connection string?
Lets say I'm connecting to different environments Prod / Dev / UAT/ Test etc...
or I want to group my servers based on some other criteria

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 way we can achive this

**1st Option** is inbuilt option that can be used to color the bottom of tab based on connection string we set

**2nd Option** is coloring tab at the Top ( I find this as very useful option since straight away alerts your eyes). My preferred choice.

[image]

ApexComplete is a **free** tool

This URL points to both the option

https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/how-to-set-different-connection-colors-in-ssms/

Hope this helps

Comment: This is no longer available from Apex for free.  It's bundled in one of their suites and costs $$$.  Apex offers "free trails" of their software if you are willing to talk to a sales rep.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it without using any external tools. Just follow these steps in SSMS

- Open *Registered Servers* tab from menu View (in my case Ctrl+Alt+G)
- Right click on *Local Server Groups* then *New Server Registration*
- In the openned window enter your connection info as well as an alias (LOCAL, UAT, RC, PROD, etc) in the *Registered server* name box.

[image]

- Go to the tab *Connection Properties*. Choose your desired default database in the top. In the bottom of the window, check *Use custom color* and the choose a color.

[image]

- Test your connection then save it.
- Open a new query window then you should see the window like below.
- **Note:** You should always connect to your server through Registered server tab in order to see your tabs in custom color mode.

[image]